# C# : Killing a specific file opened and not all instance

Tags: c#, file, process, kill, taskkill

I'm trying to open an excel file in my application via Process.
When the form is closed I want to close that file automatically .
The issue that I'm facing is even if I specify the PID process of the Excel opened .
When I run the kill instruction, all the other excels file opened will close and not specifically the one that I need.

Could you please help me .

```
 File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, bytes);
 proc = new Process();
 proc = Process.Start(filePath);
 processId = proc.Id; //keep PID to kill that process 

  proc.WaitForInputIdle(); //Set focus on opened file
  SetForegroundWindow(this.Handle);                        
  proc.Dispose();
// killing the process after file use
  Process processes = Process.GetProcessById(processId);
  processes.Kill();
```

Comment: Never needed to do it, but if the process was started passing the Excel filename as an argument, you could check its [arguments property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments?view=net-6.0)

Comment: The real problem is using `Process.Start` to open an Excel file. If you want to control Excel use Excel interop, open the file and then close it.

Comment: Besides, there's no reason to start a new Excel application every time a user double-clicks on an Excel file (that's what you're actually doing).

Comment: As you've discovered, Excel only uses a single process, so the whole concept of killing the process to close one file is flawed. As Panagiotis says, you should consider using Interop instead.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : I gived the excel file as an example but it could be any other file a word doc a pdf etc... If I specify the file name I could just stp the concerned file ?

Comment: No, I don't think there's a general solution to this. To close a file, you always need to tell the application that's having it open to close it.